# How to get the PHB before release?

Tags: dnd-5e

Several questions on this site are referencing and quoting the PHB, yet as far as I can tell, the book will not be released until the 19th [as stated on the Wizards website](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_playershandbook).

How do you (legally) get an early copy before the book enters mass market release?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Game stores that are a part of the Wizards Play network have been (and will be) sent materials 11 days earlier than their release. So, the best way to get an early release copy of the PHB (and the MM and DMG when they drop), is to head on over to your FLGS and see if they are in stock.

Also, for the PHB only, it will be for sale at GenCon which is next week.

To find out whether your local game store is part of the Wizard Play network you can *ask them*. Or, you can go to Wizards' [website](http://locator.wizards.com/#brand=dnd).

Comment: plus [three of our users received advance copies](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4753/1204)

Comment: @doppelgreener as far as I know, SE has *only* sent out copies of the starter set, not the PHB.

Comment: Thank you. Now I just have to decide if the 40% discount from Amazon is worth the wait.

Comment: @dopplegreener The winners of the community vote on meta (myself included) only won a copy of the starter kit (which was quite nice). There's a separate mini-raffle for one of the 3 of us to win a PHB in addition to the main PHB raffle but neither have occurred yet.

Comment: And everyone in my home city turned green...